# Probability of being inside $p$-dimensional ball

Tags: probability

A point $x$ is chosen inside the $p$-dimensional unit ball $B(0,1)$ (centered at the origin) with uniform probability.

What is the probability $P\big(||x||_2<r\big)=P\big(x\in B(0,r)\big)$ where $0\leq r\leq 1$?

I can't figure out how to solve this without first having to come up with a way to write out a general expression for the volume of a $p$-dimensional sphere.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball

Comment: In general, scaling a $p$-dimensional shape by a factor of $r$ means the volume scales by a factor of $r^p$, so the probability is $r^p$ (and this generalizes to a lot of situations besides hyperspheres and Euclidean metrics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just notice that

$$P(||x||_2 < r) = P(x \in B_r(0))$$

so we just have to find the ratio

$$\frac{|B_r(0)|}{|B_1(0)|}$$

but we know that $|B_r(0)| = r^p|B_1(0)|$ so the answer is $r^p$.

(Is it clear why $|B_r(0)| = r^p|B_1(0)|$?)

Comment: It makes intuitive sense that you are correct about $|B(0,r)| = r^p |B(0,1)|$. However, I don't see mathematically why that is necessarily true for volumes without first having an explicit expression for the volume as a function of $r^p$

Comment: @Dan this is the similarity rule to which you are used to: take a cube. if the length of the sides are doubled, the area of each side becomes $4\times$ larger and the volume becomes $8\times$ larger. This holds true as you move up the dimensions. Is this convincing enough?

Comment: I understand the intuition. But I can also easily write the volume of a hypercube with side length $r$ as $V(r)=r^p$ and see this. It does seem intuitive that for more complicated shapes a proportional scaling by $r$ in all directions will result in a volume scaling of $r^p$. Is the formalization of this intuition all that is needed to show this in general?

Comment: @Dan I would say so, yes. If you are familiar with integrals, you could also do it by first considering that the volume of the ball of radius $r$ is given by $\int_{B_r(0)} 1dx$ and then use a change of coordinates to change that integral into an integral over $B_1(0)$. That will also make the $r^p$ appear.

Comment: Haha the integral was what I was trying to avoid. Cheers

Comment: @Dan Of course, but I am not telling you to solve the integral. I was just asking you to relate $\int_{B_r} 1dx$ and $\int_{B_1}1 dx$, which is easier.